# Extracting precipitation data on CHIRPS v2.0

Tags: python, netcdf, extract

I have downloaded daily precipitation data from CHIRPS v2.0 and want to create a time series. The data is nc file format. But the resulting array in rain data have all value of -9999.9

```
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np


fp = 'C:/Users/navar/OneDrive/Desktop/New folder/chirps-v2.0.1981.01.days_p05.nc'
ds = nc.Dataset(fp)

time = np.array(ds.variables['time'])
lat = np.array(ds.variables['latitude'][1100:1200])
lon = np.array(ds.variables['longitude'])
rain = np.array(ds.variables['precip'][:,1100:1200,:])
```

Comment: Could you share the data link? There may not be data in the range you specified.

Comment: Hi @KadirŞahbaz. thank you for commenting, I downloaded the data on this link https://data.chc.ucsb.edu/products/CHIRPS-2.0/global_daily/netcdf/p05/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resulting array in rain data don't have all value of `-9999.9`. Since the number of elements to be printed is large, the array is truncated.

```
print(rain.max()) # => 206.28024
```

There are 432427 different pixel values in all 31 bands.

```
print(len(np.unique(rain))) # => 432427
```

When you print it out, you see the values inside the orange area (no data area) in the image:

[image]